# angular 5 testing - configure testbed globally

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, testbed

I want to import certain modules for all testing suits such as ngrx Store, ngx translate or httpClientModule in an angular-cli@1.50 project with angular 5.

in the generated test.ts I have added a test.configureTestingModule

```
const testBed: TestBed = getTestBed();

testBed.initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

testBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
    ]
}
```

Still in a user.servive.spec.ts it says no provider for Store.

user.service.spec.ts

```
describe('UserService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [UserService]
        });
    });

    it('should be created', inject([UserService], (service: UserService) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

Does the Test.configureTestingModule in user.service.spec "overwrite" the one from test.ts?

If so, how can I configure the TestBed on a global level to avoid importing repetitive modules?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have your userService, but I'm pretty sure the error is because you forgot to import the Store service in your testbed. What is the constructor of your userService ?

Comment: i didn't forget, i want to import and provide the store globally for all tests, that why i've imported it in test.ts

Comment: Tests are made in one file and are not global (for all I know). If you want to 'make it global', you will have to make an utils file that is able to construct a testbed, then call it in a beforeEach in every file.

Comment: thats what some other blogs have hinted, but thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that `TestBed` hooks into Jasmine's `beforeEach` and `afterEach` callbacks which resets the testing module between EVERY test. This gives you a clean-slate for each unit test.

This means that you cannot use `TestBed.configureTestingModule` inside your test.ts file. You must do it for each spec manually or write your own default test setup utilities to handle it.

I'm the dev for [`shallow-render`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shallow-render) which does have a solution for this by using `Shallow.alwaysProvide()` to globally setup/override/mock providers and `forRoot`ed providers in your test environment. The rest of your test module setup is handled by the library.

https://github.com/getsaf/shallow-render#global-providers-with-alwaysprovide

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer covers the way `configureTestingModule` works before/after individual tests, but you don't necessarily have to use a plugin to have a simple "always provide" module setup.  I created a `paths` alias in my testing tsconfig:

```
        "paths": {
            "@testing": ["src/testing/index"],
            "@testing/*": ["src/testing/*"]
        }
```

This lets me write a `TestModule` module with all the shared imports:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // All repeated modules
  ],
})
export class TestModule { }
```

Then, each call to `configureTestingModule` only needs to `import { TestCommon } "@testing/test-common.module"` and include it in the `imports` section of the test module config.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to  go for a separate library just to achieve this. You can create a global TestBed just by creating a common angular module where you can define a utility method. This utility method creates the TestBed which you can then reuse across all your spec files.

You can refer to the answer below which also includes sample code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64835814/4184651

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I still ended up here in 2024 while looking for solutions for global testbed configuration.

I desperately needed to mock a root service globally, and I wanted to find a solution that didn't require touching all `spec.ts` files (like with e.g. referencing a base test config).

After hours of search I realized that you can apply a global configuration embarassingly easily in the `test.ts` file (for example) by simply calling Jasmine's global `beforeEach()` method, and inside that calling `TestBed` functions:

```
beforeEach(() => 
  // Or other configuration functions
  TestBed.overrideProvider(ServiceOrComponentName, { useValue: MockName })
);
```

To further clarify, this is how an example `test.ts` could look like with the simple global configuration addition:

```
// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

beforeEach(() => 
  // Or other configuration functions
  TestBed.overrideProvider(ServiceOrComponentName, { useValue: MockName })
);
```

I'm not an expert in frontend unit testing, but this solution so far proved to be working in a robust manner in our project without any side effects.